# Is LocalStorage variable exists: if statement does not work after element reloading (page is reloading after submiting reloaded form)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Please help to fix an algorithm and prevent reloading after clicking submit: 
my website has to check, does user ever entered a nickname. If he did, then website have to show his name, if did not, then ask to type it. If the user decided to change it, he will click "reset username".

After clicking "reset" user has to submit twice his name  (after first click on "Set" total page is reloading, and after second click it is reloading only one element). Please help to fix it  - user has to submit it only once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var formNewName = '<form id="new-task"> <input id="nickN" autocomplete="off" autofocus placeholder="Write your nick" type="text"> <input id="submitname" type="submit" value="Set new name1"> </form>';
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            document.querySelector('#setnewname').onsubmit = () => {
            var newname;
            localStorage.setItem('localN', newname);
            document.querySelector('#nickName').innerHTML = formNewName;
            // Stop form from submitting
            return false;
            };
        });
        // Checking does user entered his name
        if ( !localStorage.getItem('localN') || localStorage.getItem('localN')=="undefined" )
        {   var nick;
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                    document.querySelector('#nickName').innerHTML = formNewName;
                    document.querySelector('#new-task').onsubmit = () => {
                        nick = document.querySelector('#nickN').value;
                        localStorage.setItem('localN', nick);
                        document.querySelector('#nickName').innerHTML = "Your nick is: <b>" + localStorage.getItem('localN') + '</b>';
                        // Stop form from submitting
                        return false;
                    };
                });
        }
        else
        {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                document.querySelector('#nickName').innerHTML = "Your nick is: <b>" + localStorage.getItem('localN') + '</b>'; 
            });  
        }
   </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "nickName"></div>
    <div id = "newname">
        <br>
        <form id="setnewname">
            <input id="submitreset" type="submit" value="Reset nick name">
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>
```

Update: `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();` does not helps to solve the problem.

Comment: So if i understand correctly you want user to enter name and after click in submit you need to show it?

Comment: Yes, you are right - I'd like to show the name after clicking set in reloaded form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Russian language branch of StackOverflow I had received an answer (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/901260/291735):

**HTML**

```
<div id = "nickName">
          <form id="new-task">
      <input id="nickN" autocomplete="off" autofocus placeholder="Write your nick" type="text"> 
        <input id="submitname" type="submit" value="Set new name1"> </form>
</div>
    <div id = "newname">
        <br>
        <form id="setnewname">
            <input id="submitreset" type="submit" value="Reset nick name">
        </form>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var setName = document.getElementById('submitname');
var reset = document.getElementById('submitreset');
var nickN = document.getElementById('nickN');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('localN')!== null){
document.querySelector('#nickName').innerHTML = "Your nick is: <b>" + localStorage.getItem('localN') + '</b>'
  }
})

setName.addEventListener('click', function(){
var newName = document.getElementById('nickN').value;
localStorage.setItem('localN', newName);
document.querySelector('#nickName').innerHTML = "Your nick is: <b>" + localStorage.getItem('localN') + '</b>'
})

reset.addEventListener('click', function(){
delete localStorage['localN'];
document.querySelector('#nickName').innerHTML = '<input id="nickN" autocomplete="off" autofocus placeholder="Write your nick" type="text"> <input id="submitname" type="submit" value="Set new name1">'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply if you are still having it, i couldn't see where you are taking the value from user in your code there's no input field where user can type so i'll add that and then on id submitreset you'll do this:
i work with jquery most so the syntax for that will be

```
// HTML CODE TO ADD
<input type="text" name="entername" id="entername">

// than in jquery for the submit button you already have
$(document).on("click","#submitreset",function(e){
   e.preventDefaults();
   var name = $(this).val();

   // you can print the value in the div with this id
   $("#nickName").html(name);


});
```